# generate writing in individual circles in html

Tags: html

I am trying to write a basic html file, which is essentially one page with a bunch of information. I've written the html file but am now trying to improve its appearance. For the heading of the page I have:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>

<h1> my web </h1>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

which is basically the name of the website.

Next, I am trying to alter the heading so that each letter is in an individual circle:

[image]

I can produce an individual circle with:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 70;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'purple';
      context.fill();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But aren't sure of how to go from here to produce the desired outcome.

Any pointers of how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you need to use a canvas? This can be done pretty easily with straight CSS.

Comment: You don't really need Canvas to display letters in circles. You can do this in pure CSS, just google "CSS Shapes"

Comment: Look into the CSS `border-radius` property and don't use `<center>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start. You could easily add a gradient to get a convex look.

```
h1 {
    display: table-row;
}
h1 .letter {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 .spacer {
    width: 1em;
    display: table-cell;
}

<h1>
    <span class="letter">a</span>
    <span class="letter">d</span>
    <span class="letter">d</span>
    <span class="letter">s</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <span class="letter">u</span>
    <span class="letter">p</span>
</h1>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/djrhcesL/)